# How to fix the failed to open stream: No such file or directory when I'm uploading a file(jpg)

Tags: php, laravel, file, file-upload

I'm working on the file upload task. When I'm trying to upload a file on-page, it is throwing me the following error. I checked the syntax looks good. Can anyone help me in fixing this issue?

**Code**

```
if(array_key_exists('fileToUpload', $request->all()))
            {
                $access_time = Carbon::now()->format('mdYHis');
                $directory = storage_path() . "app/public/huntSchedule";
                $files = $request->fileToUpload;
                $filename = $access_time.'_photo'.Auth::user()->id.'.'.$files->getClientOriginalExtension();
                \File::copy($files,$directory.'/'.$filename);
                $schedule->photo = 'storage/huntSchedule/'.$filename;
            }
```

***Error Message***

```
ErrorException {#442 ▼
  #message: "copy(/var/www/html/testdreamhunt/storageapp/public/huntSchedule/09132021101356_photo1.PNG): failed to open stream: No such file or directory"
  #code: 0
  #file: "/var/www/html/testdreamhunt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php"
  #line: 250
  #severity: E_WARNING
  trace: {▶}
}
```

Comment: I think it's easier to do `$request->file('fileToUpload')->storeAs('public', 'huntSchedule/'.$filename)`

Comment: But, I don't know, How to store it in the database table?

Comment: If you just store `$schedule->photo = 'huntSchedule/'.$filename` you can use `Storage::driver('public')->get($schedule->photo)` to retrieve it afterwards, unless you mean you want to store the actual file contents in the database